# Can not access com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil From nativeInterface

Tags: android, codenameone

Can not access com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil From nativeInterface in codenameone as this structure is not available in the CodenameOne.jar.
Do I need to import any other jar in classpath? Need to access the activity of codenameOne from the native interface by the below code:

```
private static Activity activity() {
    return com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
}
```

But I am getting this error while deploying:

Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.

```
/tmp/build313004297852547361xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/MyNativeImpl.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
private static Activity activity() {
               ^

 symbol:   class Activity
```

location: class MyNativeImpl
/tmp/build313004297852547361xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java:4684: error: cannot find symbol
        if (android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(CodenameOneActivity,String)
  location: class ContextCompat
/tmp/build313004297852547361xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java:7117: error: cannot find symbol
        if (android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(CodenameOneActivity,String)
  location: class ContextCompat
/tmp/build313004297852547361xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java:7122: error: cannot find symbol
            if (!forceAsk && android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CodenameOneActivity,String)
  location: class ActivityCompat
/tmp/build313004297852547361xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java:7135: error: cannot find symbol
                android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                                                     ^
  symbol:   method requestPermissions(CodenameOneActivity,String[],int)
  location: class ActivityCompat
/tmp/build313004297852547361xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java:7152: error: cannot find symbol
                return android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                                                               ^
  symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(CodenameOneActivity,String)
  location: class ContextCompat
/tmp/build313004297852547361xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/MyNativeImpl.java:56: error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(MyNativeImpl,Class)
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,
                                ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; MyNativeImpl cannot be converted to String)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; MyNativeImpl cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: can you share your codenameone_settings.properties?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it will mark it as inaccessible in the IDE but when you send the builds to the servers it should work just fine.

This is mentioned in the [native interfaces tutorial](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).

Comment: Do you have an `import android.app.Activity;` statement in your native code?

Comment: Thanks,The previous error resolved but getting below error during build:Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build8751756459645007307xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/MyNativeImpl.java:57: error: as of release 8, 'this' is allowed as the parameter name for the receiver type only, which has to be the first parameter
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity().this,
                                          ^
1 error
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: I noticed you opened other questions that received answers so I'm guessing this question should be marked as answered?